How to align absolute elements
I have an input field that looks like this
    <div className="relative">
      <input
        className="peer border h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6 focus:outline-none"
        type="text"
      />
      <label className="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4">
        Name
      </label>
    </div>

I did not set padding for either the input and the label, but they are not aligned.

What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it.

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please use custom style like input{padding:10px;}

The cause is from the <input> element having a border while the <label> does not. This makes the <input> horizontally offset by 1px, the width of the border.
You could consider:

Applying left: 1px instead of left: 0 to the <label>:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="relative">
  <input
    class="peer border h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6 focus:outline-none"
    type="text"
    value="Name"
  />
  <label class="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4 left-px">
    Name
  </label>
</div>




Applying margin-inline: 1px to the <label>:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="relative">
  <input
    class="peer border h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6 focus:outline-none"
    type="text"
    value="Name"
  />
  <label class="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4 mx-px">
    Name
  </label>
</div>




Applying a 1px transparent border to the <label>:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="relative">
  <input
    class="peer border h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6 focus:outline-none"
    type="text"
    value="Name"
  />
  <label class="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4 border border-transparent">
    Name
  </label>
</div>




Use outline instead of border on the <input> element:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="relative">
  <input
    class="peer outline outline-1 outline-[theme(borderColor.DEFAULT)] h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6"
    type="text"
    value="Name"
  />
  <label class="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4">
    Name
  </label>
</div>




Use box-shadow instead of border on the <input> element:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.16"></script>

<div class="relative">
  <input
    class="peer ring ring-1 ring-[theme(borderColor.DEFAULT)] h-12 w-52 focus:pt-6 focus:outline-none"
    type="text"
    value="Name"
  />
  <label class="absolute left-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all peer-focus:top-1/4">
    Name
  </label>
</div>



